# Namespaces in C formal definition

Tags: c, namespaces, language-lawyer

I'm reading the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) Standard and have a problem to understand the wording of the ***name space*** definition. Here is it:

> 1 If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible
>   at any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context
>   disambiguates uses that refer to different entities. Thus, there are
>   separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as
>   follows:
>
> — label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label
>   declaration and use);
>
> — the tags of structures, unions, and
>   enumerations (disambiguated by following any<sup>32)</sup> of the keywords
>   struct, union, or enum);
>
> — the members of structures or unions; each
>   structure or union has a separate name space for its members
>   (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the member
>   via the `.` or `->` operator);
>
> — all other identifiers, called ordinary
>   identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration
>   constants).
>
> <sup>32)</sup> There is only one name space for tags even though three are possible.

Here they are talking about in case of more than 1 declaration of particular identifiers is visible. Now words something like "To access an identifier one shall specify its namespace" or "To access an identifier in a specific namespace...".

Comment: What's your question? In case you are thinking about C++ namespaces, that's entirely different.

Comment: @Nelfeal Defnitely not about C++ namespaces. I want to uderstand the percise meaning of namespaces in C and rules how to work with them.

Comment: Note that macros cut across all these namespaces indiscriminately, but they've ceased to be an issue by the time these namespaces are discussed.  (C11 [§6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p1): _Macro names and macro parameters are not considered further here, because prior to the semantic phase of program translation any occurrences of macro names in the source file are replaced by the preprocessing token sequences that constitute their macro definitions._)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me show an example first (this is *strictly* for understanding purpose, dont write code like this, *ever*)

```
#include  <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int here = 0;    //.......................ordinary identifier
    struct here {    //.......................structure tag
        int here;    //.......................member of a structure
    } there;

here:                             //......... a label name
     here++;
     printf("Inside here\n");
     there.here = here;           //...........no conflict, both are in separate namespace
     if (here > 2) {
         return 0; 
     }
     else
       goto here;                 //......... a label name

    printf("Hello, world!\n");          // control does not reach here..intentionally :)
    return 0;
}
```

You see usage of identifier `here`. They belong to separate namespace(s) according to the rule, hence this program is fine.

However, say, for example, you change the structure variable name, from `there` to `here`, and you'll see a conflict, as then, there would be two separate declaration of same identifier (ordinary identifier) in the same namespace.

Comment: @Lundin: It's quantum physical code — it is both `here` and `there`.

Comment: @Lundin It's somewhere, I guess...not count the _time_ factor, either. :)